# DateTime format in MVC controller Edit Action

Tags: model-view-controller, .net-core

I have a Create view that allows a user to add Title and Date. When the user goes to edit it should show the Title and Date when it was created. I'm not sure how to do this.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Edit(int id)
    {

        var iDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");

        var editViewModel = new CreateEditViewModel
        {
            Id = id,
            AsOf = ToEdit.AsOf,
            Title = ToEdit.Title,               
            )                
        };
        editViewModel.AsOf = DateTime.ParseExact(iDate, "MM/dd/yyyy 
     HH:mm", null);
        return View(editViewModel);
    }
```

I am currently using DateTime.Now in the Edit Action in the controller but I know this isn't correct because it was show the current date/time insted of the date and time that it was originally created.

Comment: Anyone able to help, please.

Comment: Why won't anyone on this forum help me anymore. The last two things I've posted no one has helped.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the model to edit from a database?